# Analysis and complexity of a 2-3-4 Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, 2-3-4-tree

I have been asked to construct a 2-3-4 tree from a sequence of elements in a top down and bottom up approach. I was able to do this as its quite straight forward.

Next, I was asked to analyse the running-time of the algorithms and also find out what the complexity of the problem is i.e. how fast can a 2-3-4 tree be constructed from a given sequence of elements?
This is where it gets confusing for me, so far I understand the complexity to be O(logn) since the algorithm does not need to traverse the entire tree to insert new elements. However, how do I analyse the running time of the algorithm? I always thought running time and complexity to be sort of the same thing.

Comment: Maybe they were asking you for a lower bound of the problem?

Comment: Possibly, but this is how it was asked.

Comment: You can say that you can't build a search tree in less than O(n log n) time using only comparison between elements because otherwise you'd be able to sort O(n) elements in less than O(n log n) time, which is impossible if you only use comparisons.

Comment: So that would be the "complexity" of the problem. Maybe they asked you this so you can say that your solution is theoretically optimal (unless it's not strictly true for integers, as you can sort them using radix sort and then build the tree in linear time from the sorted sequence).